# Angulartics Piwik - Which line(s) should I comment in tracking code?

Tags: single-page-application, matomo, angulartics

I'm using angulartics to track a single web app. Angulartics documentation says that in order to work properly I need to comment automatic tracking lines and I quote:

"Make sure you delete any automatic tracking line from your vendor snippet code!"

```
// Google Analytics example
ga('send', 'pageview'); // <---- delete this line!
```

Since I'm using piwik I'll attach the snipet of code that they provide:

```
<!-- Piwik -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    var _paq = _paq || [];
    (function(){ var u=(("https:" == document.location.protocol) ? "https://{$PIWIK_URL}/" : "http://{$PIWIK_URL}/");
    _paq.push(['setSiteId', {$IDSITE}]);
    _paq.push(['setTrackerUrl', u+'piwik.php']);
    _paq.push(['trackPageView']);
    _paq.push(['enableLinkTracking']);
    var d=document, g=d.createElement('script'), s=d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; g.type='text/javascript'; g.defer=true; g.async=true; g.src=u+'piwik.js';
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(g,s); })();
</script>
<!-- End Piwik Code -->
```

My question here is, what lines should I comment?
The following ...

```
_paq.push(['setTrackerUrl', u+'piwik.php']);
_paq.push(['trackPageView']);
```

?

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2):

Piwik uses following line to start tracking page views:

```js
_paq.push(['trackPageView']);
```